# Wait for a button event (Java, Swing)

Tags: java, swing, events, button, joptionpane

Im training my skills and I decided create my own JOptionPane (something similar not same). To do this I created my own class called BOptionPane1:

```
public class BOptionPane1 implements ActionListener{

    private JFrame container;
    private JButton buttonYes;
    private JButton buttonNo;
    private JButton buttonCancel;

    public enum  buttonState {BUTTON_YES, BUTTON_NO, BUTTON_CANCEL};
    public static buttonState actualState = null;

    public BOptionPane1(){

    }

    public buttonState ShowBOptionPane1(){

        this.container = new JFrame("Dialogo");
        this.container.setSize(300, 100);
        this.container.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.container.setVisible(true);

        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        this.container.setLayout(flowLayout);

        this.buttonYes = new JButton("Yes");
        this.buttonNo = new JButton("No");
        this.buttonCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

        container.add(buttonYes);
        container.add(buttonNo);
        container.add(buttonCancel);

        buttonYes.addActionListener(this);
        buttonNo.addActionListener(this);
        buttonCancel.addActionListener(this);

        //Here, my strange custom component will have been created by ShowBOptionPane1
        //Now I need wait until user click a button, after that, test() will be called.

        return test();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        switch (e.getActionCommand()){
            case "Yes":
                this.actualState = buttonState.BUTTON_YES;
                break;
            case "No":
                this.actualState = buttonState.BUTTON_NO;
                break;
            default:
                this.actualState = buttonState.BUTTON_CANCEL;
                break;
        }
        this.container.setVisible(false);
    }

    public buttonState test(){
        return this.actualState;
    }
}
```

**This class is used by this another:**

```
public class ViewExample{

    public ViewExample(){

        JFrame backContainer = new JFrame("Titulo ViewExample");
        backContainer.setSize(500, 300);
        backContainer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        backContainer.setVisible(true);

        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        backContainer.setLayout(flowLayout);

        JButton buttonPlay = new JButton("Play");
        JButton buttonStop = new JButton("Stop");
        JButton buttonPause = new JButton("Pause");

        backContainer.add(buttonPlay);
        backContainer.add(buttonStop);
        backContainer.add(buttonPause);

        buttonStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                BOptionPane1 bOptionPane1 = new BOptionPane1();
                BOptionPane1.buttonState result = bOptionPane1.ShowBOptionPane1();
                System.out.println("Este es el resultado: " + result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Finally, this is my main class**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ViewExample cursoVideotutoriales = new ViewExample();
    }
}
```

**So I would like that in my BOptionPane1 class after run ShowBOptionPane1 
method I could wait until  the user click a button, after that, test() 
method would be called and It would return a buttonState variable**

P.D. I know that my BOptionPane1 background could be a Jpanel or another different component but how I said It doesn´t matter I am training so I dont mind this kind of things.

I hope I explained well.

*Update: I was looking for information and I think that to solve this question I should work with "Threads" and methods like "Wait" and "Notify" or something similar I`m not sure. Does somebody knows if I am in the correct way?

Comment: Use a modal JDialog, not a JFrame as the parent container.

Comment: Ty camickr, I did it and It is better than JFrame ;)

Comment: Regarding, `"Ty Ryan It could be a solution but I´m not sure that It works, however, I will try it. On the other hand, I think that the correct solution would be using something like "threads" with "waits and notify" I'm not sure....Anybody knows or can say me if I'm in the correct way. TY Everybody ;)"` -- no the correct solution is not using threads or waits or notify, but to do what @camickr suggests above.

Comment: Ok @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, how I said I did it but that is only a suggestion to do It better but It is not the solution for my problem (I think) so if you can contribute with something It would be nice...ty

Comment: Yes, that **is** the solution, the only solution, the one solution. Full stop. Be sure that the JDialog is modal, that you pass in the parent JFrame into its constructor.

Comment: mmm...now I don`t have any Jframe in my code @camickr said me that I would have to use a JDialog NOT a JFrame so I deleted my old JFramme and now I have JDialog...I am not understanding you when you say: "JDialog is modal, that you pass in the parent Jframe into its constructor"...What JFrame??